# jQuery table sort (not filtered with button in field search)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use a search button inside the input. However, I added the button at the input, but the table does not return me the data in the search, could someone help me? I have something wrong that I can not see. =/

**The below are 2 jsFiddle exemplifying:**

- the first is ok - filtering successfully

> [jsfiddle.net/xk4mx58j](http://jsfiddle.net/xk4mx58j)

```
$('table#tabLeBank').each(function(){
    var table = $(this)
    var headers = table.find('th').length
    var filterrow = $('<tr>').insertAfter($(this).find('th:last()').parent())
    for (var i = 0; i < headers-1; i++){
        filterrow.append($('<th>').append($('<input style="width:100%" class="form-control text-uppercase">').attr('type','text').keyup(function(){
            table.find('tr').show()
            filterrow.find('input[type=text]').each(function(){
                var index = $(this).parent().index() + 1
                var filter = $(this).val() != ''
                $(this).toggleClass('filtered', filter)
                if (filter){
                    var el = 'td:nth-child('+index+')'
                    var criteria = ":contains('"+$(this).val()+"')"
                    table.find(el+':not('+criteria+')').parent().hide()
                }
            })
        })))
    }
    filterrow.append($('<th>').append($('<input style="width:100%" class="btn btn-link">').attr('type','button').val('Clear Filter').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type=text]').val('').toggleClass('filtered', false)
        table.find('tr').show()
    })))
})
```

- the second is the problem (not filtering successfully)

> [jsfiddle.net/xuo7kgL7/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/xuo7kgL7/3/)

```
$('table#tabLeBank').each(function(){
    var table = $(this)
    var headers = table.find('th').length
    var filterrow = $('<tr>').insertAfter($(this).find('th:last()').parent())
    for (var i = 0; i < headers-1; i++){
        filterrow.append($('<th id="th'+i+'">').append($('<div class="input-group"><input class="form-control text-uppercase" id="iconified_tab'+i+'" placeholder="search"><span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button></span></div>')))
          }
    // only id1
    $('#th1 #iconified_tab1').attr('type','text').keyup(function(){
            table.find('tr').show()
            filterrow.find('input[type=text]').each(function(){
                var index = $(this).parent().index() + 1
                var filter = $(this).val() != ''
                $(this).toggleClass('filtered', filter)
                if (filter){
                    var el = 'td:nth-child('+index+')'
                    var criteria = ":contains('"+$(this).val()+"')"
                    table.find(el+':not('+criteria+')').parent().hide()                 
                }
                    alert($(this).val());
            })
        })
    filterrow.append($('<th>').append($('<input style="width:100%" class="btn btn-link">').attr('type','button').val('Clear Filter').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type=text]').val('').toggleClass('filtered', false)
        table.find('tr').show()
    }))) })
```

Comment: It is working, it's just case-sensitive. The `text-transform: uppercase` doesn't change the actual value of the input box, it just changes the display.

Comment: @Stryner sorry the second link (jsfiddle) was wrong,  I updated now...

Comment: @Stryner can help me now??